# How to pull information of virtual guests of a KVM host using Python?

Tags: python, api, kvm

I tried with libvirt. Unfortunately libvrt does not support KVM completely, and I have been constantly getting error messages and warnings stating, that it does not support the platform. Is there an alternate package or method that someone can suggest

Answer (score 3):

1. Virtualbricks, CLI : http://www.virtualbricks.eu/
2. KVM-Admin, CLI : http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Kvmtools
3. Ganeti, CLI : http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/current/html/

These three software are what you looking for : Python made and not based on libvirt.

---

I still using libvirt without any problem, so I maybe can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

the following script written by russel bartini may be helpful to you. this is a python script for managing, backup and restoring the VM running on KVM.

Here is the link :[virt-back.py](http://russell.ballestrini.net/virt-back-restoring-from-backups/)